# Make a custom PHP page pull into Joomla template

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I may be trying to overthink this or I may have just missed an answer somewhere that does what I want. I have a set of php pages that are written in the Joomla API, but don't have the template around them. What I am wondering is there an easy way to have these pages have the joomla template that is selected for my site? I almost started down the path of just creating another php page in the template folder and then I thought about trying just to pull in the elements of the template into my pages. There has got to be a simple way.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What exactly do you want to do? You want to write a template for Joomla? or you want to put some PHP files in Joomla?

Comment: I have a template and I have some separate php files that render HTML. I want those php files to have the template around them. I could just use the Sourcerer extension for Joomla and include them in a blank article but I figured there might be a better way.

Comment: I use the templates all the time, I just grab the default template from the cms database and use that path. Or you could just set the path and assign the template name in your standalone application.  I mean its more complicated than that because you don't have the Jdocs, but you can definitely get the css etc.  sort of like here https://github.com/elinw/Content--Play/blob/master/web/content/index.php#L96

Comment: @chrislhardin I think the best practice is to create a component or module based on your content and put your php code in module or component views.